# Another Scrapy Question: Output to Console but not to .json

Tags: python, scrapy

This is another newbie scrapy question:

When I first started with the scrapy tutorial linked here:

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html

I can crawl a webpage and then output the scraped content to a json file. But when I modify the tutorial to add a few rules like:

- traversal depth
- and memory so it doesn't traverse already visited pages again.

The output to the json stops although I can still see the output on the console. Can someone give me pointers on what I am doing wrong? The modifications can be seen below:

```
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    #allowed_domains = allowed_domain_list
    start_urls = input_domain_list
    max_depth = 1
    invalid_url = []

    def parse(self, response):

        from_url = ''
        from_text = ''
        depth = 0
        # Extract the meta information from the response, if any
        if 'text' in response.meta:
            from_text = response.meta['text']
        if 'depth' in response.meta:
            depth = response.meta['depth']
        if 'visited' in response.meta:
            visited_dict = response.meta['visited']
        else:
            visited_dict = {}
        if response.status == 404:
            self.invalid_url.append(response.url)
            print('*'*80)
            print('INVALID LINK')
            print('*'*80)
        else:
            page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
            web_page = response.request.url
            ext_text = ' '.join([item.strip() for item in
                response.xpath('//body//text()').extract() if item.strip()])
            visited = visited_dict.get('{0}'.format(web_page))
            print('-'*80)
            print('VALID LINK; Depth: {0}; Visited: {1}'.format(depth, visited))
            print('-'*80)
            yield {'text': ext_text,
                   'source': web_page}
            if not visited and depth <= self.max_depth:
                for selector in response.xpath('//a/@href'):
                    if selector is not None:
                        link = selector.get()
                        request = response.follow(link, callback=self.parse)
                        request.meta['visited'] = visited_dict
                        request.meta['visited'].update({'{0}'.format(web_page): 1})
                        request.meta['depth'] = depth + 1
                        print('*'*80)
                        print(link, request.meta['visited'])
                        print('*' * 80)
                        yield request
```

Comment: Sorry, why you need `visited`? Scrapy by default not scrape duplicate URLs.
If you need duplicates, you can use dont_filter - https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html

Comment: As @Serhii says you don't need to manually filter already visited urls. Nor should you need any custom traversal depth code. Look at the [docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html?highlight=depth#module-scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth)